# With the Mixcloud API how would you search for shows that have a specific track in them?

Tags: api, mixcloud

I want to be able to search for all shows that contain a specific track using the Mixcloud API.

Looking through the documentation for the Mixcloud `https://www.mixcloud.com/developers/`, as well as the Ruby library I was debating using: `https://github.com/actfong/mixcloud`, I can't see this functionality exposed, is there a way to do it that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was possible quite not a long time ago, but it seems that Mixcloud has disabled this feature in the API.

An example app, that implemented this kind of search: https://github.com/mixcloud/Mixcloud-LazyDJ

Funny thing is that it's official and still powered in the mixcloud.com domain.

Check out this code:

```
 $.getJSON(LazyDJ.host + '/track/' + artistSlug + '/' + trackSlug + '/?callback=?', function(response) {
    results = [response];
    addResults();
    if (getTO !== null) {
        clearTimeout(getTO);
        getTO = null;
    }
});
```

Additionally, it also worked using a classic WWW URL scheme, like:
http://mixcloud.com/track/eric-prydz/call-on-me

Was never documented or supported though, since the main site revamp few years ago.

I've send an email to the support crew regarding re-enabling of this feature, since I have been extensively using it for private purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately seems like that endpoint (https://api.mixcloud.com/track/TRACK_AUTHOR/TRACK_TITLE) isn't active anymore. Any other idea to achieve this? 